# C++: Where to place files using #include <> with angle brackets

Tags: c++, opengl, boost

Context:

I am trying to run the code for a thin-plate spline provided by Jarno Elonen at http://elonen.iki.fi/code/tpsdemo/. It requires the installation of OpenGL + GLUT and the Boost uBlas library. I have downloaded the code, but I have been unable to run it because the compiler can't locate the GLUT and Boost files.

I'm hoping that someone can get the code on the website to run (and not just address the immediate trouble I'm facing), and tell me the exact steps to follow to get it to run. (I don't mind if you dumb it down completely, I'm a beginner :) )

What I have done so far:

- Downloaded and extracted tpsdemo-1.2.tar.gz from the website above
- Downloaded FreeGLUT (because various online forums told me I should be doing this as GLUT itself is outdated...): Freeglut 3.0.0 from freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download.
- Downloaded Boost: boost_1_61_0.zip from www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_61_0.html.

I don't know what to do from here... where should I put these files so that the code from tpsdemo-1.2 can access them? I have tried putting it in the same directory, but this seems to require using `#include "filename"` with quotation marks instead of the `#include <filename>` with angle brackets which is in the provided code. If I do alter it like this, then it seems like I will have to change all include statements in GLUT and Boost (which currently use angle brackets) which is not a small task. (I don't really want to be modifying too much code...) What's the correct way to do this? I have tried using the `-Idir` tag while compiling but this runs into other problems, although I don't know if this problem is to do with GLUT/Boost (which is why I'd like to see if anyone else can get the code to run!)

Comment: The way to do it is to use `-Idir`

Comment: @hum what operating system, compiler/build system are you using? the answer will vary depending on those factors

Answer (score 1):

wedge brackets in a`#include` are for denoting files that exist on a system or framework level. As such you *never* get them there by moving them into the "right" place, but instead you specify which directories are to be considered "system" or "framework" level. The exact method in the end is depending on the compiler used, but all major compilers out there understand the `-I${PATH_TO_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY` command line option notation. `-I…` may be specified multiple times to specify multiple directories.

It is a good style to use wedge bracketed includes exclusively for headers that are 3rd party to a project and/or for headers that form the framework of a project. For headers that belong to modules of a project itself quotation marks should be used.